# Omniauth: Facebook callback kills dev server

Tags: ruby, facebook, crash, omniauth, net-http

I'm following the code here:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth?autoplay=true

I'm on ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]
and Rails 3.0.7

Basically, I have my own user model (no Devise/AuthLogic). I created a SessionsController to handle the Facebook callback:

```
match "/auth/facebook/callback" => "sessions#create"

def create
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = User.find_by_email(auth["user_info"]["email"]) || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Finally, my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :facebook

  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :facebook, :presence => true

  def self.create_with_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
    user.email = auth["user_info"]["email"]
    user.facebook = Facebook.create!(:uid => auth["uid"])
  end

end

class Facebook < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  validates :uid, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
end
```

When I run this on localhost and grant the app access, it hits my dev server and kills it. This is the stack trace (consistently reproducible):

```
-- control frame ----------
c:0060 p:---- s:0340 b:0340 l:000339 d:000339 CFUNC  :connect
c:0059 p:0011 s:0337 b:0337 l:000150 d:000336 BLOCK  /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2    -p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678
c:0058 p:0031 s:0335 b:0335 l:000334 d:000334 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-    p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44
c:0057 p:0026 s:0323 b:0323 l:000322 d:000322 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-    p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:87
c:0056 p:0444 s:0317 b:0317 l:000150 d:000150 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678
c:0055 p:0011 s:0309 b:0309 l:000308 d:000308 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637
c:0054 p:0048 s:0306 b:0306 l:000305 d:000305 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626
c:0053 p:0025 s:0303 b:0303 l:000302 d:000302 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168
c:0052 p:0499 s:0296 b:0296 l:000295 d:000295 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/faraday-0.5.7/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:45
c:0051 p:0041 s:0283 b:0283 l:000282 d:000282 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/faraday-0.5.7/lib/faraday/request.rb:85
c:0050 p:0044 s:0276 b:0276 l:000275 d:000275 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/faraday-0.5.7/lib/faraday/request.rb:27
c:0049 p:0065 s:0270 b:0270 l:000269 d:000269 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/faraday-0.5.7/lib/faraday/connection.rb:177
c:0048 p:0069 s:0263 b:0263 l:000262 d:000262 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/oauth2-0.1.1/lib/oauth2/client.rb:63
c:0047 p:0039 s:0254 b:0254 l:000253 d:000253 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/oauth2-0.1.1/lib/oauth2/strategy/web_server.rb:15
c:0046 p:0070 s:0244 b:0244 l:000243 d:000243 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/oa-oauth-0.2.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:87
c:0045 p:0042 s:0240 b:0240 l:000239 d:000239 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/oa-oauth-0.2.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb:31
c:0044 p:0146 s:0237 b:0237 l:000236 d:000236 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/oa-oauth-0.2.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:66
c:0043 p:0411 s:0233 b:0233 l:000232 d:000232 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/oa-core-0.2.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:49
c:0042 p:0019 s:0228 b:0228 l:000227 d:000227 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/oa-core-0.2.0/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:22
c:0041 p:0044 s:0224 b:0224 l:000223 d:000223 METHOD /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-    p180@rails3tutorial/gems/oa-core-0.2.0/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:30
c:0040 p:0014 s:0220 b:0220 l:000211 d:000219 BLOCK  /Users/andy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial/gems/warden-1.0.4/lib/warden/manager.rb:35
c:0039 p:---- s:0218 b:0218 l:000217 d:000217 FINISH
c:0038 p:---- s:0216 b:0216 l:000215 d:000215 CFUNC  :catch
[.......snipped]


Abort trap
```

My OmniAuth setup is:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, 'MY_APP_ID', 'MY_SECRET',
        { :scope => 'email, offline_access',
          :client_options => { :ssl => { :ca_file => '/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt' } } }
end
```

Tried both with and without the ssl client option and the result is the same.

For what it's worth, others have run into this too, but I can't find a solution posted anywhere. See for example:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1069

Answer (score 4):

After several frustrating hours, I found the solution here:
http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/4875

Basically, the Postgres gem ended up using a different version of OpenSSL. The details of how all that works under the hood are still not totally clear to me, but the way to get unstuck is:

1. Uninstall openssl and postgresql
2. Uninstall pg gem (gem uninstall pg)
3. Install openssl and postgresql using homebrew
4. Fork and install pg gem *from source* (I downloaded it and ran 'rake install')

This can happen even with the MySQL gem from reading around.

Finally, I'm on Mac OSX (Snow Leopard) like a lot of other developers.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this was a bit simpler than some of the other posts.
I did not have to uninstall and reinstall `openssl` or `postgresql`.
I have those two items installed via macports, and they are working fine where they are.
The problem turns out being that the ruby build process is a bit out of sync when it comes
to looking for `openssl`.  The `openssl` extension was being linked against the `macports openssl version (1.0.0)` and the digest extensions (i.e. md5, sha1, et al) were being linked against the `system openssl version (0.9.8)`.  I re-downloaded `ruby-1.9.3-p0` and recompiled with the following option:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0 --with-opt-dir=/opt/local
```

The `--prefix` argument should of course point to wherever you would normally install ruby.
This caused everything to link properly and with the same versions of `openssl`.

Just installing over your existing installation doesn't work out, then completely blow it away and reinstall it.  Then go back to your app and `bundle install`.